# Setting a VLC demuxer in an XSPF playlist

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have some files that cannot be played using the default demuxer priority in VLC (they freeze on the first frame then close.) When researching the issue I came across discussion of the exact issue I was having with a resolution that the avformat demuxer was works for these files. Passing `--demux=avformat` on the command line allows me to open a VLC instance and I can then add and play these files, but I cannot open playlists with this demuxer setting; VLC provides the following error:

`VLC can't recognize the input's format:
The format of 'file:///D:/path/here/test.xspf' cannot be detected. Have a look at the log for details.`

VLC documentation states VLC can interpret options from XPSF playlists that include elements like

`<extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
  <vlc:option>demux=avformat</vlc:option>
</extension>`

however this does not work. The video takes longer to load (the only difference in behavior I see), loads the first frame, then closes.

Answer (score 0):

Using "--demux=xspf-open,avformat" allows me to open an instance of VLC that will open both playlists and this type of video file. Taking only this step still will not allow me to double click on playlists or this type of video file and successfully load those playlists or files.

Adding or modifying the line `demux=<foo>`
in `%APPDATA/vlc/vlcrc` to begin with these demuxer options will yield the desired result; both playlist files and this type of video file will be successfully loaded and opened.

Comment: I will not select this as an answer at this time because I don't know what the consequences are of having everything go through the avformat demxuer.

Comment: Setting this as a default is not a suitable solution, you can't open any network URLs for example without modifying the settings file to remove the setting.